# The best / canonical way to preserve / access form fields' 'old' values (before they are updated)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Use cases:
I want to programmatically access the value of a form field prior to the update, for one of the following scenarios (just 2 examples, to illustrate the case)

a) I want to detect if the original value of a field has been changed in the form, before it's saved in the database
b) I want to detect / prevent changing the field value in a very specific way, e.g. if a field value is set to "Approved", it should never change back to "Pending approval", etc.

Constraint: Ideally, I would prefer not to do another trip to the database (to check for the old value), for performance reasons.

Comment: You could make a separate hidden version of each field that retains the original value.

Comment: If you work with a ModelForm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807227/1622937

Comment: Thank you! This looks exactly what I was looking for, will check and mark as answered

Comment: @user6131524 you are welcome.  Best is to mark it as a duplicate of  [Django ModelForm Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806771/django-modelform-validation)